# Problem with assigning multiple values to multiple variables in python

Tags: python, file, dictionary, split

I don't understand why my code does not work. let's say the file i'm trying to open contains this:

```
Luke,89,94,81,97
Eva,40,50,65,90
Joseph,55,58,54,99
Oliver,73,74,89,91
```

And this is the function i've written:

```
def my_func(myfile):
    out_dict = {}
    somefile = open(myfile)
    data = somefile.readlines()
    for line in data:
        name,course1,course2,course3,course4 = line
        out_dict[name] = [float(course1), float(course2), float(course3), float(course4)]
    return out_dict
print(my_func("newfile.txt"))
```

i'm trying to add each line to a dictionary where the name of each person is the key.
My problem is at line 6 where i try to assign 5 values to 5 variables. I get the value error saying "too many values to unpack (expected 5)". but when i use this line of code instead of the original one it works:

```
name,course1,course2,course3,course4 = line.split(',')
```

As far as i know something like this works:

```
v,x,z,y = "John",1,2,3
```

But why does not the original code at line 6 work as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code snippet will not work because you are trying to unpack `line` which is a string to better understand consider the following e.g. which throws an error,

```
>>> a, b = "apple strawberry"
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

So, to unpack the string you will have to split the string by delimiter of your choice in your case that will be `,`. So the following e.g. will work,

```
>>> a, b = "apple strawberry".split()
>>> a
'apple'
>>> b
'strawberry'
```

---

Now coming to solution, your file is a csv file, so it's better to use python's inbuilt `csv` module to process the `csv` file,

Use:

```
import csv

def read_csv(path):
    out_dict = {}
    with open(path) as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, skipinitialspace=True)
        for line in reader:
            out_dict[line[0]] = list(map(float, line[1:]))

    return out_dict

print(read_csv("newFile.txt"))
```

This prints:

```
{'Luke': [89.0, 94.0, 81.0, 97.0], 'Eva': [40.0, 50.0, 65.0, 90.0], 'Joseph': [55.0, 58.0, 54.0, 99.0], 'Oliver': [73.0, 74.0, 89.0, 91.0]}
```

Comment: I got it, so "lines in data" is just "one" string which can not be assigned to 5 values. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`line` is a **string of characters**. This is a specific type in Python, resulting from the reading of the lines in the file. Each line in the file returns 1 string of character with `readlines()`.

Python cannot guess how to assign your variables name,course1,course2,course3,course4 from this string. `,` has no special meaning for a string of characters.

That's why you need to tell Python to split the string on the concurrences of `,`. This will produce a **list of strings**, and in this case as the expected number of variables on the left match the number of items in the produced list on the right, it works.

Indeed, the notation `v,x,z,y = "John",1,2,3` is in fact a syntactic sugar (shortcut) for `v,x,z,y = ["John", 1, 2, 3]`. In reality it is not exactly that (read more: https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-multi-variables-values/) but it is enough for you to understand now.

Answer (score 0):

```py
data = somefile.readlines()
   for line in data:
       name,course1,course2,course3,course4 = line
```

In this case, line is a string variable, that contains one string. The whole line from the file.

This is not the same as writing
`x,y,z = "John",1,2`
but more like
`x,y,z = "John,1,2"`
which the python interpreter does not know what to do with.

The split method is told how to interpret the string (cut them at the comma) and thus can make the multiple assignments.